# run sql on Qgis

Tags: qgis, sql

I want to do simple demo to our manager with quantum gis. i have buildings from my city with wgs84 projection on postgre sql database and also have non gis table which have who leaves this buildings (people name,surmane,birth date,etc...) my demo is ; select some building with selection tool from qgis and run some sql from non gis table and show how many people leaves in selected buildings? My sql is ready for work but how can i do this scenario with quantum gis?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a join on the database (join buildings and non-spatial data) and display the join in QGIS.

Everything else is much more involved.

Comment: but simple join dont solve problem because i need group by

Comment: Well, you can group by in the join.